# Displaying streaming video on dynamic texture

Tags: unity, textures, camera, video, streaming

We are working in Unity 3D on pro licence and we are faced with the task to display streaming video as a dynamic texture in out Unity3D web project. We have a standard IP-camera , which is capable of delivering a stream h.264 format via RTSP, and mjpeg via HTTP.

How can we display this stream on a texture in our scene?

Comment: Discussion of 5 different possible solutions makes this question too broad. If you want to try one of those solutions and ask *specific* questions about the troubles you have implementing them, you should do that. I've removed that part of your question.

Comment: Http://net7mma.codeplex.com has a rtp and rtsp implementation without any external dependencies.  The codebase is written completely in c# and performance and memory is almost twice as good as competing solutions in c++.

Answer (score 2):

Unity Pro has [movie textures](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/VideoFiles.html) built in for streaming different types of movie files to an in-world texture.

If that doesn't work for you, you can build a custom solution around [RTT](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-RenderTexture.html), also a Pro feature.

AFAIK, there are already video streaming solutions available in the Unity Asset Store. A quick google search will do wonders for you.

Comment: MovieTexture work's only with ogg streams, and not perfectly as I know.
Hm, on assets store I didn't see any solutions for streaming video.
Unfortunately any custom solutions wrote on c++ not work for us, cause Unity web player builds not support native code dll's